# New to this sort of thing: Attempting to figure out a long lost Google account on Android

Tags: applications, google-play-store, gmail, 7.0-nougat, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I am very new to this sort of thing and I am really liking the possibilities that are achievable with Android. I wasn't really at all familiar with this until a few days ago and some of the things that you guys are doing is really pretty neat!

Okay, so I want to get started by saying I have a pretty big problem, and that problem is going back around this time last year.

I had used my android device to download a couple of applications through the Google Play Store, and I cannot remember for the life of me what the account in question was. I have tried to wrack my brains to figure bits and bobs out but I am only really able to achieve the dates the applications were downloaded and their times. Not what account was associated with the said applications, If I could figure out the account not just the password, that would be half of the battle.

The tricky bit is that I know that I removed the account from my device at some point and attached a new one that I use on and off, but I am in need of getting back into the prior.

I have been looking at the forums up and down, trying to scour for answers, looking at posts about Databases and rooting etc and I even attempted rooting my device today, but of course as a Newbie, what I really do not want to do is erase any of the data from the applications, or any data at all really that is on the root level. I pretty much just quit after a bit but I am trying to get myself familiar with the basics of this.

Because it was such a while ago I have been really skeptical about how long it will have been stored in any said databases etc, whether is has been replaced etc, all in all I might find nothing, but at the end of the day I just want to get to the bottom of this mess so that I am able to hopefully try and retrieve a lost account.

I have been picking up a few things on using 'Odin' and using the 'Teamwin' tools, as I said I was about to root my device using 'Magisk' but I eventually sort of gave up as I was unsure on about backing up my data and not having enough space on my device.

So, what would I do from here, at this point I am just a sitting duck, I am sort of in bits at the moment and I am all over the place trying to figure things out.

My Specifications on what device I am using are as follows:

Device: Samsung S6 /
Android Version: 7.0 Nougat /
Build: G920FXXS5EQL5

Thank you for your time!